# Notification on the top of the screen whenever a song changes

Tags: windows-10, notifications, aimp

After upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, whenever a song starts (or changes if I play a playlist) I get a notification on the top of the screen.

[image]

This happens only when I use Aimp and Windows 10 (didn't have this issue with Aimp on Windows 7).

I have disabled the notification center, but that didn't help.
I also tried to find a setting in Aimp to disable this but had no luck.

Any advice on the issue ? this is really bothering as I work while listening to music and the notification is very distracting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I have disabled the notification center, but that didn't help

> 1. Menu - > "Preferences".
> 2. Expand "Plugins".
> 3. Select "Information bar".
> 4. Uncheck "Show current file info at playback start":
>
>    [image]

Source [Topic: turn off desktop notifications of song titles](http://www.aimp.ru/forum/index.php?topic=51280.0)

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I meant windows 10 notification center..